# Connected components of an open subspace

Tags: general-topology

I apologize if this turns out to be too obvious, but I don't seem to find the right argument.

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $Y$ be an open subspace of $X$.

If $Y$ is a union of connected components of $X$, then what can be said about the connected components of $Y$? Are they exactly the connected components of $X$ contained in $Y$?

I know that connectedness is intrinsic, but I'm not sure whether maximality is preserved when passing to a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a connected component $Y_0$ of $Y$. Since it is connected, it is contained in a unique connected component $X_0$ of $X$. Since $Y$ is a union of connected components of $X$ and $Y \cap X_0 \supset Y_0 \ne \varnothing$, we get that $X_0 \subset Y$. Since $X_0$ is connected, it must be contained in the connected component of $Y$ it intersects, ie $Y_0$. So $Y_0 = X_0$ is a connected component of $X$ contained in $Y$.

Conversely suppose $X_0$ is a connected component of $X$ contained in $Y$. Then since $X_0$ is connected, it is contained in some connected component $Y_0$ of $Y$. But since $Y_0$ is connected, it must be contained in a connected component of $X$, which must be $X_0$. Thus $X_0 = Y_0$ is a connected component of $Y$.

Combining, connected components of $Y$ are exactly the connected components of $X$ that are contained in $Y$. Note that we did not need that $Y$ is open.